# Page with Update Panels stops working when moved into Content Page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages

I have a rather complex page that took me some month to work properly and that uses 10 Update Panels. Now for some structural change I had to place this working page as a content page inside a master page.

Unfortunately the buttons in the UpdatePanels don`t fire anymore after migrating to ContentPage.

MasterPage:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="contentBody" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

ContentPage:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentBody" Runat="Server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"/>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel_MainButtons" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline">
<ContentTemplate>  
<div id="DIVMainButtons" runat="server">
<asp:Button ID="ButtonDiaLibre2" runat="server" Visible="true" Text="Dias Libres" BackColor="#CDCDCD" OnClick="DiaLibreList" BorderWidth="0px" Font-Size="11px" Width="150px" useSubmitBehavior="false"/>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I had tried to place the ScriptManager in the MasterPage instead of the ContentPage, but whatever I tried the button is not firing.

---

Ok, the button does not fire because of on error in the JavaScript I use in order to safe and write back the scrolling position of a panel inside an update panel. This is the JavaScript that worked in the stand-alone page, but returns a Null reference when run in the Content page. The script is located right after the ScriptManager in the ContentPage.
scrollTop is Null or not defined!
Anyone has a clue why this does not work in the content page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var yPos;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    yPos = $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop;
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $get('scrollDiv').scrollTop = yPos;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check javascript errors on browser developer console. UpdatePanel uses AJAX calls and can stop working because of js errors anywhere on the page.

Comment: Thanks to Alex Kudryashev I consulted the developer console to find out I had a JavaScript error (see above). But I still don´t understand why!